# How can I connect to TFS without having to repeatedly type my credentials? Command line mac

Tags: macos, terminal, team-foundation-server

How can I avoid typing in credentials every time I use the TF command in terminal?

I read the [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere) and they have an answer that I do not understand.

> A: You can use Kerberos for authentication to a TFS server. More
>   information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475929%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). This article mentions the 
>   `tf profile` command because it still existed at that time this article
>   was written but that step can be skipped now all together.

I go to their location for more information, and I cannot find any other steps for commandline besides `tf profile -edit -boolean:useDefaultCredentials=true  ProfileName`.  The command `tf profile` no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to any value, such as “0.” The login credentials will be cached. To set variables you need to set it in the terminal setup files, if you use bash edit `.bash_profile`, or if you use either zsh, or oh my zsh edit `.zshrc` and add the following line to the end of the file:

`TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=0`

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190725.aspx).